# Getting rid of MS Office connected experiences

Tags: command, registry, ms-office, autohotkey

I would like to disable MS Office connected experiences through registry or command prompt or even a AutoHotkey script

[MS Office Privacy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BueYo.png)

[MS Office Privacy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZq6l.png)

[MS Office Privacy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtH0c.png)

Hope someone can help me, I swear I spent quite a lot of time searching Google for a solution to this problem but to no avail.

And the follwoing entries not existing on my registry, even after I entered them, they did not work at all, even by signing out and into windows

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\privacy]
"disconnectedstate"=dword:00000001
"usercontentdisabled"=dword:00000001
"downloadcontentdisabled"=dword:00000001
"controllerconnectedservicesenabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\common\clienttelemetry]
"sendtelemetry"=dword:00000002
```

My office is 2019 pro plus 32-bit

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more detail about what connected experiences is and what exactly you want changed? Also, could you please scroll down on your screenshot so that we can see the more important details as opposed to just the title of *Connected Experiences*?

Comment: I have added the rest screenshot for the settings windows

"Connected experiences that analyze your content are experiences that use your Office content to provide you with design recommendations, editing suggestions, data insights, and similar features. For example, PowerPoint Designer or Translator."

What I'm trying to do is to uncheck all checkboxes on this settings and close excel with registry, command prompt or anything similar.

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Are you trying to automatically uncheck the checkboxes in the dialogue as opposed to manually? Also, could you please describe how you accessed the dialogue so that we can replicate the problem on our systems?

Comment: Yes! that is right, I want to uncheck checkboxes with a hotkey>

The Access to this dialogue box is as follows:

Open Excel ---> Options ---> Trust Center ---> Trust Center Settings ---> Privacy Options ---> Privacy Settings

After unchecking checkboxes, a dialogue box will appear tells that office needs to restart in order for the changes to take effects, click "OK"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, this worked for me:

```
SetKeyDelay, 100

run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
WinWait, Excel
sleep 100
Send !t
sleep 100
Send t
sleep 100
Send {Tab 2}
sleep 100
Send {Space}
sleep 100
Send p
sleep 100
Send {Tab}
sleep 100
Send {Space}
sleep 100
Send {Tab 2}
sleep 100
Send {Space}
sleep 100
Send {Tab 2}
sleep 100
Send {Space}
sleep 100
Send {Tab 2}
sleep 100
Send {Space}
sleep 100
Send {Tab 2}
sleep 100
Send {Space}
sleep 100
Send {Tab 2}
sleep 100
Send {Space}
sleep 100
Send {Space}
sleep 100
WinClose Trust Center,
sleep 100
WinClose Excel Options,
sleep 100
WinClose Excel
Return
```

[Spyre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14362191/spyre) Thank you for your patience with me, I appreciate your help.

If you willing to help me afterwards in other automation issues, I'm ready to post additional questions soon.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want it to. If it doesn't, let me know and I'll fix it.

```
run "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
WinWait, Excel
sleep 100
Send {Tab 6}
Send {Down 5}
Send {Space}
Send t
Send {Tab 2}
Send {Space}
Send p
Send {Tab}
Send {Space}
Send {Tab 4}
Send {Space}
Send {Tab 2}
Send {Space}
Send {Tab 2}
Send {Space}
Send {Tab 2}
Send {Space}
Send {Space}
```

### Revision based on comment:

```
SetKeyDelay, 100

run "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
WinWait, Excel
sleep 100
Send !t
Send t
Send {Tab 2}
Send {Space}
Send p
Send {Tab}
Send {Space}
Send {Tab 4}
Send {Space}
Send {Tab 2}
Send {Space}
Send {Tab 2}
Send {Space}
Send {Tab 2}
Send {Space}
Send {Space}
```

### Second Revision based on comment:

```
SetKeyDelay, 100

run "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
WinWait, Excel
sleep 100
Send !t
Send t
gosub t2s
Send p
Send {Tab}
Send {Space}
Loop 5
    gosub t2s
Sleep 100
Send {Space}
Send {Esc 3}
WinClose Excel
return

t2s:
    Send {Tab 2}
    Send {Space}
return
```

### V2.A

```
SetKeyDelay, 100

run "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
WinWait, Excel
sleep 100
Send !t
Send t
gosub t2s
Send p
Send {Tab}
Send {Space}
Loop 5
    gosub t2s
Sleep 100
Send {Space}
Send {Esc 7}
Sleep 100
WinClose Excel
return

t2s:
    Send {Tab 2}
    Send {Space}
return
```

Comment: Not working, It opened "Open" section instead of option. Note that once excel is opened, Options section can be opened with ALT+T normally, but I tried to insert in to AutoHotkey script with no luck as I'm new to AutoHotkey and still trying to create many scripts to automate my work with it. Thanks

Comment: I added a revision that 1. Uses ALT+T to launch the option menu instead of Tabs, arrows, and spaces, and 2. uses `SetKeyDelay, 100` to add stability for lag on slower systems in case that's what is causing the problem @JameelKalwan. Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: It worked but i would like to also uncheck "Optional Diagnostic Data", as well as close Excel windows. Thanks

Comment: I just added that functionality as well. Feel free to let me know if the script does not work properly or if there is another feature that you want it to include. If this revision solves the problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: The last script didn't uncheck the boxes in addition to the appearance of the following message:

https://i.imgur.com/REY3dYm.png

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of your full screen when that dialogue appears?

Comment: Looks like I just need to spam the Escape key more before attempting to WinClose. I added another revision, let me know how it works. @JameelKalwan

Comment: Wait, did it not uncheck any of the boxes?

Comment: Unfortunately, The same dialogue box appeared again. And yes, the script no longer uncheck the checkboxes.

Comment: Any news about the script?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but I'm taking a day off for New Years Day. I'll be taking another look at this tomorrow.

Comment: Hello Spyre! Did you spend a good day off?

Comment: I've taken another look at it, but I'm unable to reproduce what you are experiencing at this point. Each of the methods that I've tried above successfully unchecks all of the boxes and close Excel. Since I cant reproduce your problem, I am going to recommend that you check out tools such as [Pulover's Macro Creator](https://www.macrocreator.com/), which you can use to record keystrokes and mouse actions and automatically convert them into an AHK script. I hope this helps you solve your problem!